# What if we don't explain any external_labels in Prometheus for Thanos?

Tags: prometheus, thanos

If we don't explain any `external_labels` in Prometheus configuration file for Thanos, what will happen?

For example, I have two Prometheuses and they are scraping the same endpoint, so their external_labels is like this:

prometheus1:

```
global:
  external_labels:
    replica: 1
```

prometheus2:

```
global:
  external_labels:
    replica: 2
```

At this point, we know that two kind of metrics will be saved in the object storage, metrics with replica=1 label and replica=2 label.
If I delete the external_labels from configuration file, how many metrics will be saved in the object storage?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.
based on this [doc](https://thanos.io/v0.3/thanos/getting-started.md/#external-labels),

> Every Prometheus instance must have a globally unique set of
> identifying labels.

And if you don't declare one for your Prometheus, TSDB blocks wont be uploaded to your object storage and you gonna receive this error from sidecar:

```
level=warn ts=2020-10-03T17:00:14.826489487Z caller=sidecar.go:274 err="upload 01EKQPFYHW6R8TB48N07NSCH8P: empty external labels are not allowed for Thanos block." uploaded=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm doing the same with 2 Prometheus instances scraping the same endpoint. I'm also using different replica names for both Prometheus. What could be the issue, any idea?